# Get a result from two DB tables and set it and another Jframe in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, object

I am working on an application that generates the data of a beneficiaries of some grants; So I have DB contains many table: A table contains the information principle of a person "beneficiary" (id, name, job, etc.), others tables "table of car grant", "table of marriage grants" etc. So these contains the information of grants and each row in the grants tables has a foreign key of the person from the first table "beneficiary".

My problem is when I look in the DB for some beneficiary and found it I search for all his grants by his "id". Means I make two search related in two different tables; So I do this:

```
 query="SELECT * FROM travailleur WHERE ncompte=?";

   try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
    c.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)){

      preparedStatement.setString(1, vncompte);
    result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    /***/

    if(result!=null){
result.last();  
 size = result.getRow();
  result.beforeFirst();  
  System.out.println(size);
ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();
int j=0;
String data[][] = new String[size][resultMeta.getColumnCount()];
String vector[] = new String[size];
while(result.next()){
     for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++){
         data[j][i-1]=result.getString(i);
         vector[j]=result.getString(1); 
      }//end for
         j=j+1;

        }//end while
    dat=data;
   v = vector;/*this vector contains id of result*/
     ro=size; /*this value contain the number of result elements*/

  }//end try

 Object dhadj[][]= new Object[0][6]; /*create this table to put the grants of  each person have found by the previous search*/

/*this for boucle to generate all id*/
 for(int i=0;i<ro;i++){
       int d;
       d=Integer.valueOf(v[i]);

        query="SELECT * FROM hadj WHERE id=?";
  try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)){
           System.out.println("doing hadj");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, d);

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
 if(rs!=null){
   rs.last();  
  int siz = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();  

 ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
int a=0;
        Object dha[][] = new String[siz][6];

while(rs.next()){
   //  for(int ii = 1; ii <= rsMeta.getColumnCount(); ii++){
         dha[a][0]=rs.getString("id");
         dha[a][1]=rs.getString("idh");
         dha[a][2]=rs.getString("ticket");
         dha[a][3]=rs.getString("montant");
         dha[a][4]=rs.getString("datei");
         dha[a][5]=rs.getString("nombrep");
     // }//end for
         a=a+1;

//do your other per row stuff 
        }//end while
        /*here appendvalue I want to add the result of each id in one big table, but this doesn't work*/
         dhadj= appendValue(dhadj,dha); 

    }else{ dhadj[0][0]=Integer.toString(d);
            for(int ii = 1; ii < 6; ii++){
             dhadj[0][ii]="";  
          }
         }
  }//end try             

     }//end for v
```

Is it correct?

I also have a second problem that is how to add an `Object[][]` to another `object[][]`.

I create a `Object[][] dhadj=null` and in a loop for I create another `object[][]` `dha`, so at the end of every loop I add `dha` to `dhadj`. How I do that?

Comment: Can't you join those two tables and get a single result?

Comment: You made this much more complicated then it has to be. You can retrieve all the info with one query by using the `JOIN` clause and you can use `List` objects or `Map`s instead of arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks about JOIN, 
But maybe there is another grants relate with the same person perhaps in the grants table..so that's why I make a table...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough details to create a solution specific to your problem but I will create a model which you can use, I hope it helps.

First, create a class to use as a container to store the info retrieved from the database:

```
public class Person{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Date date;
    public String value1;

    public Person(int id, String name, Date date, String value){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
}
```

Then retrieve the info from the database and store it as a `List` of `Person` objects.

```
List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
try(Statement st = con.createStatement()){
    try(ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT t1.id as id, t1.name as name, t2.date as date, t2.value as value FROM persons as t1 LEFT JOIN values as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id")){
        while(rs.next()){
            personsList.add(new Person(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getDate("date"), rs.getString("value")));
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The important part in the SQL statement is `LEFT JOIN` which is use to retrieve the data from two table at once (matching the rows in this two tables that have the same value for the `id` column).

You can find more about `LEFT JOIN` [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Ok thanks about JOIN, But maybe there is another grants relate with the same person perhaps in the grants table..?

Comment: @Joseph you can join more then one table, you can extract data from three tables with a single query if that is what you need.

Comment: I have more than 16 tables with different data, You know what I mean !!
.
What I am doing is when I find the id from the first table, I search by these id in others table ..